# Swagger UI keeps loading

Tags: java, swagger, spring-webflux, openapi

Hi I am using spring reactive programming and using below dependencies. when i am hitting swagger url in browser it's keep loading. Could someone helps what mistake i am making

my swaggar config class:

```
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "springdoc.info")
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    private String title;
    private String version;
    private String teamName;
    private String email;
    private String website;
    private String externalDocs;

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI openAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info()
                        .title(title)
                        .description("APIs to perform CRUD operation")
                        .version(version)
                        .contact(new Contact()
                                .name(teamName + " Team")
                                .email(email)
                                .url(website)
                        )
                )
                .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation()
                        .url(externalDocs)
                        .description("wrapper Documentation")
                );
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi myOpenApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("Wrapper APIs")
                .pathsToMatch("/**")
                .build();
    }
}
```

my controller interface have these configs:

```
@Operation(
        operationId = "getIntegratedParty",
        summary = "Find Integrated Party by cdpPartyId or businessId",
        responses = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {
                        @Content(mediaType = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = IntegratedParty.class))
                }),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "No Integrated Party found for given Id", content = {
                        @Content(mediaType = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = Error.class))
                }),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error", content = {
                        @Content(mediaType = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = Error.class))
                })
        })
@GetMapping(value = "/dummy/{id}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
Mono<ResponseEntity<dummy>> getParty(@Parameter(name = "id", required = true, description = ID_DESCRIPTION) @PathVariable String id,
                                                         @Parameter(name = X_CORRELATION_ID, description = X_CORRELATION_ID_DESCRIPTION) @RequestHeader(value = X_CORRELATION_ID, required = false) String correlationId);
```

my application.yaml file

```
springdoc:
  info:
    title: PartyDB Wrapper APIs
    version: 1.0.0
    teamName: myteam
    email: myteam.com
    website: "dummy url"
    externalDocs: "dummy url"
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
    path: /api-docs
    groups:
      enabled: true
  swagger-ui:
    enabled: true
    path: /swagger-ui
```

```
spring boot version '3.0.6'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.0.2'
compileOnly 'jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0'
```

Can anyone help what mistake i am making